# React Native - let return() wait until variable is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I am getting data in an asynchronous way and consequently showing it inside the `render()` function using `{data}`.

Now my question is, how do I let the `render()` function wait until the variable is defined? Currently either the placeholder variable doesn't change or it never arrives.

This is my code,

```
let [data] = useState();

    let storeData = async (value) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('locatie', value)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    let getInfo = async () => {
        data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('locatie');
        return data;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getInfo().then(r => console.log('getInfo called, data var = ' + data))
    })

    console.log('return() initiate, data var = ' + data)
```

And showing it here:

```
<TextInput value={data !== undefined ? data : 'placeholder'} onChangeText={(value) => storeData(value)}/>
```

Evidently, since it's asynchronous, `render()` happens before the function.

Any help would be appreciated. Please no flame  I use React Native first time :)

Also, please note that it's inside a function, I am not using classes and will not use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn more about using react hooks. Anyway, you can refer to below for your issue.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState('');

const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    setData(value);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('locatie', value);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const getInfo = async () => {
  const res = await AsyncStorage.getItem('locatie');
  setData(res);
};

useEffect(() => {
  getInfo();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it, now I can't edit* the `TextInput`?

Comment: You should add `setData(value)` to `storeData` function. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `let [data] = useState();`
write `const [data, setData] = useState();`
and update the state inside the `useEffect` hook inside a `then()`
in your case, after the promise returns some data.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! But could you elobrate some more? If the `data` is a `constant`, how am I supposed to update it? The first error I get is that `data is read-only`

Comment: @danielmz02 I think you need to read more React documentation and/or tutorials about state. You use the `setData` function to update the value, not change it directly.

Comment: @GuyIncognito interesting.